Passing on the torch
DearJapanese.SE community,
I have had a wonderful time in this community and I would like to thank you all for your interesting questions, your knowledgeable answers, and most of all for making Japanese.SE such a welcoming place. After almost nine years I have asked the Community Team to revoke my moderator diamond. Over the past few years, I have slowly faded into the background but I would like to bid you a proper farewell before passing on the torch to someone more capable. I will remain a member, but due to other commitments (work, family and otherwise) I don't expect to be able to contribute much in the foreseeable future.
I wish you all many many more prosperous years of Q&A!
All the best,
Earthliŋ

ええ～ さびしくなります(T_T)。。。

Wishing you all the best for your future. Thanks for everything you've done and we'll see you around!
